# looking for jar file that contains JuiCEProviderOpenSSL

Tags: java, jar, ws-security

Does anyone know about the container jar file for the class given below. Please send me the link....
org.apache.security.juice.provider.JuiCEProviderOpenSSL

or any other work around for this issue

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.security.juice.provider.JuiCEProviderOpenSSL
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:185)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.loadProvider(WSSConfig.java:605)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.addJceProvider(WSSConfig.java:662)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.staticInit(WSSConfig.java:306)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.<init>(WSSConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getNewInstance(WSSConfig.java:333)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getDefaultWSConfig(WSSConfig.java:342)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecBase.<init>(WSSecBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecEncryptedKey.<init>(WSSecEncryptedKey.java:56)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecEncrypt.<init>(WSSecEncrypt.java:106)
    at fi.xmldation.ApplicationManager.AxisHeaderImpl$WSSecuritySample.addBinaryTokens(AxisHeaderImpl.java:90)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/juice/dist/juice-jdk14-0.9.0.zip) is a very old one but I don't know if a newer version exists at all.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of CXF do you use?

Remember that `CXF 2.3.3` needs `WSS4J 1.5.x`. `CXF 2.4.x` uses `WSS4J 1.6.x`.